# In E. J. Patten’s book Return to Exile, what is the tree like thing

Tags: character-identification, object-identification

In the book, Solomon Rose fought one of these things. The tree thing was described as having white eyes and mouth and eyes looked like they were cut out.

 Also, which identification would be correct?